# Shell: how to determine that no lines in a text file exceed 2048 bytes in length

Tags: shell, text-files, posix

I realize it's very unlikely that the size of a single line in a text file would ever organically exceed 2048 bytes in size. But I still think it would be very valuable to know how to make sure it wasn't the case

Edit: Just wanted to say that the reason I asked this question is because I'm writing a script that verifies that a file is a text file as defined by POSIX. One of the requirements is that no line in a text file shall exceed {LINE_MAX} bytes in length (newline inclusive). On Ubuntu and FreeBSD this value is 2048.

On GNU Linux you need not worry about this limitation, as it will allow a line length that is bound only by memory. FreeBSD, however, does impose this limitation, and I've recently made a serious effort to learn FreeBSD, so I think it's an important thing for me to able to do.

Edit: I think I was wrong about FreeBSD. I'm able to process lines that exceed 2048 bytes in length with grep

Comment: Do you mean *bytes*, *characters* or *graphemes*? These are three different things, and depending on the locale the resulting solution might be very different.

Comment: Beware JSON files!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will literally find the number of bytes:

```
LANG=C grep -E '^.{2049}' some.txt
```

For example:

```
$ printf é | LANG=C grep -E '^.{2}'
é
```

If you instead mean *characters,* use the relevant `LANG` value or don't set it to rely on your shell default:

```
$ printf é | LANG=en_US.utf8 grep -E '^.{2}'
$ echo $?
1
```

If you mean *graphemes*, use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147616/3645):

```
printf  | grep -Px '\X{2}'
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Good answer, but difficult to understand for people unaware of the possibility to set an environment variable at the start of the command. You can add functions `has_overflow_char` and `has_overflow_byte` that will take a filename as input and return 0/1.

Comment: @l0b0 Great answer. But should the first example be 'LANG=C grep -E '^.{2048}' some.txt'? It would seem that grep -E starts counting at 0 and that it treats the newline character as being a 1-byte character

Comment: @HaroldFischer No, try `printf 'a\n' | grep -E '^.{2}'` - it doesn't match. The newline is not counted.

Comment: printf '\n' | LANG=C grep -E '^.{0}' returns a match where    printf '' | LANG=C grep -E '^.{0}' does not... let me check this on Linux, I'm using FreeBSD right now

Comment: @l0b0 Yeah, you are correct, it is completely ignoring newlines, either trailing or leading

Comment: l0b0 I guess the one limitation of this is that if every line in a file is terminated with a newline, `LANG=C grep -E '^.{2048}' some.txt` is actually finding lines that are greater than 2048 bytes in length because grep it is not accounting for the newline. Or does the newline character not have a size?

Comment: This is getting rather academic. `grep` does not include the newline character, but also does not check for it, so if you literally want to take it into account you have to use a much slower and more complex solution like `read` which returns exit code 1 if the last line of a file is not newline terminated.

Comment: @l0b0 I don't see it as being academic. In the vast majority of cases, one can expect a line to be terminated with a newline. Thank you for excellent answer, it helped me greatly

Comment: @l0b0 In the first two examples, would LANG=C and LC_ALL=C have the same effect? Have read that the latter is preferable in covering the case where the user has forced a value for LC_ALL

Answer (score 0):

You can see how many lines are too long:

```
cut -b 2049- < inputfile | grep -c '.'
# When you want to count chars, not bytes, use "-c"
cut -c 2049- < inputfile | grep -c '.'
```

You can use this in a function

```
checkfile() {
   if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
      overflow="$2"
   else
      overflow=2049
   fi
   cut -b "${overflow}" < "$1" | grep -c '.' > /dev/null
}

# Run test
testfile=/tmp/overflow.txt
echo "1234567890" > "${testfile}" # length 10, not counting '\n'
for boundary in 5 10 20; do
   echo "Check with maxlen ${boundary}"
   checkfile "${testfile}" ${boundary}
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo File OK
   else
      echo Overflow
   fi
   # example in check. Look out: the last ';' is needed.
   checkfile "${testfile}" ${boundary} || { echo "Your comment"; echo "can call exit now"; }
   # checkfile "${testfile}" ${boundary} || { echo "${testfile} has long lines" ; exit 1"; }
done
```